# Injected script and https

Tags: javascript, https, safari-extension

Are Safari extension injected scripts allowed to access secure pages? When I try to hit GMail's secure page I get in the console.log "Script Cancelled" at "ServiceLogin".

Answer (score -1):

I should hope not. Make sure you're actually going to GMail's secure page; make sure you haven't picked up any unknown extensions and do a virus and spyware scan.

Lastly, not sure this is the right place to ask about that - You might do better on a specifically security-oriented site.

Comment: Sorry, I am writing the extension. :)

Comment: Hmm looks like global.html can access https pages but injected scripts cannot. That is odd.

Comment: And I changed my URL in the injected script to https://login.yahoo.com, seeing the same failure with "Failed to load resource: cancelled" in console log.

Comment: It's probably reacting to it like a virus; best if you find some other method. If you managed it, it would be an exploit they'd have to fix.